# How to send a JSON abject using Axios in React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, post, axios

I've been trying to post an object using the code below:

```
const modifiedEvent = {
            Event : {

            }
        };
modifiedEvent.Event["eventname"] = name1;
modifiedEvent.Event["eventId"] = "" + 2;
modifiedEvent.Event["eventTypeId"] = "" + 3;

axios.post(URL, modifiedEvent)
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

The API expects an object in this form:

```
{
    "Event" : {
        "eventname" : "SomeName",
        "eventId" : "1",
        "eventTypeId" : "2"
    }
}
```

but I keep receiving this error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 502.

The thing is that I'm allowed to make connections to the API if I use JSON.stringify(), but I can't post my data as a string. It has to be an object. I'd appreciate if someone helps.

Comment: I got it fixed, I was passing a wrong parameter, that was not expected by the API.